# Regex Expression Working in Debugger but returns empty list in Python - REGEX

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that is working in the Regex101.com debugger, but then when I try to use it on my data in Python, it returns an empty list.  I have tried this with and without carats, with and without the $, wrapping the regex in parentheses and not, triple backticks v. double quotes.  What am I missing here?

```
dates = [x for x in mylist if re.match(r"^(('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2,4}')|('\d{2}\/\d{4}')|('\d{2}\/\d{2,4}.+'))$", x)]
```

Below are true matches in mylist:

```
   my list = ['01/01/2018', '01/01/18', '01/2018J', '01/2018AB', '01/2018/DEFGH']
```

Comment: Can you give a sample input?\

Comment: @Nick, can you help? I'm a little confused about how to fix.

Comment: @Nick:  Those aren't needed in a python `r"xyz"` "raw" string.

Comment: @wallyk that's cool. makes life much easier!

Comment: I don't think you should have the single quotes in your regex...

Comment: @Nick, yes, that was it - thank you.

Comment: [r"(?m)^(('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2,4}')|('\d{2}/\d{4}')|('\d{2}/\d{2,4}.+'))$"](https://regex101.com/r/sNei6T/1)

Answer (score 0):

In your `mylist` , each element did not contain `'` and i can not understand why you are using `.+` , which will match almost everything. I feel you want to match this

```
import re
mylist = ['01/01/2018', '01/01/18', '01/2018J', '01/2018AB', '01/2018/DEFGH']
regex = r"((\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2,4})|(\d{2}\/\d{4})|(\d{2}\/\d{2,4}))"

dates = [re.search(regex,x).group(0) for x in mylist ]
print(dates)
# ['01/01/2018', '01/01/18', '01/2018', '01/2018', '01/2018']
```